# python regex to split string at <a> elements and extract link + text

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have several `<a>` elements in string:

```
s = 'Hello world. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a> is a great website. <a href="https://www.espn.com/">ESPN</a> is another great website.'
```

The goal is to split the string so I get a list similar to the one below:

```
l = [
    "Hello world. ",
    {"link": "https://stackoverflow.com/", "title": "StackOverflow"},
    " is a great website. ",
    {"link": "https://www.espn.com/", "title": "ESPN"},
    " is another great website.",
]
```

The dictionaries can be any object I can extract the link and title from. Is there a regex I can use to accomplish this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are not supposed to use regex on HTML. Use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is better tool to parse this string than regex. As general rule, don't use regex to parse HTML:

```
s = 'Hello world. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a> is a great website. <a href="https://www.espn.com/">ESPN</a> is another great website.'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

out = []

for c in soup.contents:
    if isinstance(c, NavigableString):
        out += [c]
    elif isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == 'a' and 'href' in c.attrs:
        out += [{"link": c['href'], "title": c.text}]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Hello world. ',
 {'link': 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'title': 'StackOverflow'},
 ' is a great website. ',
 {'link': 'https://www.espn.com/', 'title': 'ESPN'},
 ' is another great website.']
```

Comment: Is it possible to recognize also link both with and without `a href` ? Like this one: `s = 'Hello world. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a> is a great website and https://www.espn.com is another great website'`

Comment: @itajackass HTML parser is used only to parse tags, if there aren't any tags (like in your example), other tools have to be used (for example `re` module)

Comment: Thanks.I need to try a good reg_exp for url. at today i've not found any good regular expression that work great..

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using regex for this:

```
import re

s = 'Hello world. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a> is a great website. <a href="https://www.espn.com/">ESPN</a> is another great website.'
sites = [{"link": link, "title": title} for link, title in zip(re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)">', s), re.findall(r'>(.*?)</a>', s))]
print(sites)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [{'link': 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'title': 'StackOverflow'}, {'link': 'https://www.espn.com/', 'title': 'ESPN'}]
> ```